# how to iterate this dictionary object -- myDictionary<int, List<myClass[]>> so that the Key and element values are on the same output line?

Tags: c#, dictionary

In the following code I have an object class called `InputData`, and then in a dictionary object I add a `List<InputData[]>` as a parameter, and then I populate this dictionary object (including `InputData[]`), and each dictionary element contains a List of an `InputData[]` array.  In order for me to iterate through the elements of this dictionary I use a couple of sub `foreach` loops to get to the elements of `InputData[]`.

My question is How can I iterate the elements of this dictionary object and the elements of `List<InputData[]>` so that I can display all the data for each dictionary element on the same `Console.WriteLine(...)` in the main `foreach`loop?

Right now I have a main `foreach` loop (for the output of this dictionary object) and then 2 sub `foreach` loops where the first sub `foreach` loop iterates the `List<...>` and the 2nd sub foreach loop itereates `InputData[]`.  Is it possible to access the element data in the same (main) `foreach` loop as the Key value?

```
class InputData
{
   public int dataId;
   public int dataQtr;
   public string dataThing;

   public InputData(int DataId, int DataQtr, string DataThing)
   {
       dataId = DataId;
       dataQtr = DataQtr;
       dataThing = DataThing;
   }
}

//----------------------------------------------------

List<InputData> input_rows = new List<InputData>
{
   new InputData(1, 1, "chair" ),
   new InputData(1, 1, "mug" ),
   new InputData(1, 2, "bottle" ),
   new InputData(1, 3, "dog" ),
   new InputData(2, 2, "snake" ),
   new InputData(2, 3, "horse" ),
   new InputData(3, 2, "cup" ),
   new InputData(3, 3, "boomerang" ),
   new InputData(3, 3, "girl" ),
   new InputData(3, 4, "walkman" ),
};

Dictionary<int, List<InputData[]>> d = new Dictionary<int, List<InputData[]>>();

foreach( var row in input_rows )
{
   List<InputData[]> list;
   if( !d.TryGetValue( row.dataId, out list ) )
   {
      var a = new InputData[4];
      a[row.dataQtr - 1] = row;
      d.Add( row.dataId, new List<InputData[]> { a } );
   }
   else
   {
      var fa = list.FirstOrDefault( a => a[row.dataQtr - 1] == null );
      if( fa == null )
      {
         var a = new InputData[4];
         a[row.dataQtr - 1] = row;
         list.Add( a );
      }
      else
      {
         fa[row.dataQtr - 1] = row;
      }
   }
}

//--is there a way I could eliminate to the 2 sub foreach loops here?  How?
foreach(var pr in d)
{
   List<InputData[]> a = pr.Value;
   foreach(var b in a)
   {
      foreach (var c in b)
      {
         if (c != null)
            Console.WriteLine(c.dataThing);
      }                        
   }
   Console.WriteLine(pr.Key);  //--I want to display c.dataThing on the same line as pr.Key
}
```

Comment: try to append each c.dataThing to a string or StringBuilder object with the suitable delimiter and append with pr.key and then write to console

Comment: it seems what you are trying to do can be simplified a lot more if you use right data structure... `Dictionary<int, List<InputData[]>>` doesn't seems right ,at all, and its very unclear what its used for... I think you should fix this first or you are gonna have more problems in future,

Comment: Someth like `d.Select(i => new { key = i.Key, Value = string.Join(" ", i.Value.SelectMany(v => v.SelectMany(t => t.dataThing))))` might work, haven't tried though

Comment: I just tried  the d.Select(.....) but got an error when t.dataThing is null -- how to compensate in this linq when t.dataThing is null?  maybe something like   ...    t => t.dataThing ? t.dataThing, 'empty')

Comment: @richdvc you can do this `t => t.dataThing ?? ""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, you can do this:

```
var output = d.Select(i => new { Key = i.Key, Value = string.Join(" ", i.Value.SelectMany(v => v.SelectMany(t => t.dataThing ?? ""))));
foreach(var o in output) Console.WriteLine(output.Key + " " + output.Value);
```

Comment: I came up with this which also works -- var k = d.Select(i => new { key = i.Key, Value = string.Join(" ", i.Value.SelectMany(v => v.Where(u => u != null).SelectMany(t => t.dataThing))) }); ---- one problem though -- the value is not picking up dataQtr, only dataThing.  Is there a modification so that it can include dataQtr?  Also, the " " is not being applied, it returns just one long string for each key value.

Comment: OK -- finally!!!   ----  I came up with this from the suggestion by KMoussa which does what I want ----  var k = d.Select(i => new { key = i.Key,  Value = string.Join("", i.Value.SelectMany(v => v.Where(u => u != null).SelectMany(t => t.dataQtr + "-" + t.dataThing + "|"))) }); --- I took out the space in " "  and made it "" for the string.Join which is require for this to work.  Many thanks to all of you and to KMoussa for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use `StringBuilder` to first build the line and then show it in the Console

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var pr in d)
{
   List<InputData[]> a = pr.Value;

   //Add the key to the string builder
   sb.Clear() ;
   sb.Append(String.format("Key:{0}", pr.Key)) ;

   foreach(var b in a)
   {
      foreach (var c in b)
      {
         if (c != null)
         {
            sb.Append(String.format("Data:{0}",c.dataThing));
         }
      }                        
   }
   Console.WriteLine(sb);  
}
```

Comment: I guess this is one approach for putting all the output on the same Console.WriteLine(...) line, but it doesn't eliminate the nested foreach loops.  I take that to mean that in my current design there is no escaping the nested foreach loops.